# Laravel jetstream teams, When switching users how to change home page from dashboard to a different page?

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

I am using Laravel jetstream teams and I would like to changed the default page (dashboard) when switching teams to a different page I have made (myteams), How do i change the default location when switching teams in the navigation? thank you

Comment: in `RouteServiceProvider`

Answer (score 0):

in `App/Providers/RouteServiceProvider` you can find this

```
/**
     * The path to the "home" route for your application.
     *
     * This is used by Laravel authentication to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public const HOME = '/dashboard';
```